# Examples of HTTP API Rate Limiting HTTP Response headers

Tags: http, rest, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429

One of the Additional HTTP Status Codes ([RFC6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585)) is

- [429 Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4)

Where can I find examples of HTTP / REST API Rate-Limiting HTTP response headers useful with this HTTP response status?

Comment: Also, the way to use these headers is different. `response.headers["x-ratelimit-limit"]`

Answer (score 154):

Here are some examples of HTTP API Rate Limiting HTTP Response headers. Taken from four common REST APIs: Github, Vimeo, Twitter and Imgur:

#### Github Rate Limiting http://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting

```
#=============================#=============================================#
# HTTP Header                 # Description                                 #
#=============================#=============================================#
| X-RateLimit-Limit           | Request limit per hour                      |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-Remaining       | The number of requests left for the time    |
|                             | window                                      |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

#### Vimeo Rate Limiting http://developer.vimeo.com/guidelines/rate-limiting

```
#=============================#=============================================#
# HTTP Header                 # Description                                 #
#=============================#=============================================#
| X-RateLimit-Limit           | Request limit per day / per 5 minutes       |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-Remaining       | The number of requests left for the time    |
|                             | window                                      |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-Reset           | The remaining window before the rate limit  |
|                             | resets in UTC epoch seconds                 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

#### Twitter REST API Rate Limiting https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1

> *Note:* Twitter uses headers with similar names like Vimeo, but has another dash in each name.

```
#=============================#=============================================#
# HTTP Header                 # Description                                 #
#=============================#=============================================#
| X-Rate-Limit-Limit          | The rate limit ceiling for that given       |
|                             | request                                     |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-Rate-Limit-Remaining      | The number of requests left for the         |
|                             | 15 minute window                            |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-Rate-Limit-Reset          | The remaining window before the rate limit  |
|                             | resets in UTC epoch seconds                 |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

#### Imgur API Rate Limits http://api.imgur.com/

```
#=============================#=============================================#
# HTTP Header                 # Description                                 #
#=============================#=============================================#
| X-RateLimit-UserLimit       | Total credits that can be allocated         |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-UserRemaining   | Total credits available                     |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-UserReset       | Timestamp (unix epoch) for when the credits |
|                             | will be reset                               |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-ClientLimit     | Total credits that can be allocated for the |
|                             | application in a day                        |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| X-RateLimit-ClientRemaining | Total credits remaining for the application |
|                             | in a day                                    |
+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: If you're designing your own rate-limit headers, the Best Current Practice BCP178 is a relevant resource, recommending that the X- prefix be deprecated. Check out the original RFC/BCP for more info. http://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp178

Comment: Great examples, I made a Node.js package that can be used with the `request` package: https://github.com/webjay/x-rate

Answer (score 39):

In addition to API specific headers, don't forget the humble, [standard `Retry-After` header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3)

> Servers send the "Retry-After" header field to indicate how long the
> user agent ought to wait before making a follow-up request....
> The value of this field can be either an HTTP-date or a number of
> seconds to delay after the response is received.

The standard makes specific *additional* recommendations when using it with a 503 or 3xx status code:

> When
> sent with a 503 (Service Unavailable) response, Retry-After indicates
> how long the service is expected to be unavailable to the client.
> When sent with any 3xx (Redirection) response, Retry-After indicates
> the minimum time that the user agent is asked to wait before issuing
> the redirected request.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764075/retry-after-http-response-header-does-it-affect-anything

Comment: `Retry-After` is intended to be used with `503` or `30x` responses https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.3

Comment: @Russbear but nothing in that section indicates it can't be used with other response codes.

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests: "The response representations SHOULD include details explaining the condition, and MAY include a Retry-After header indicating how long to wait before making a new request." https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6585#section-4